# How to retrieve milliseconds from java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java

I have a timestamp object  and need to get the milliseconds from it, can someone help me with an example code snippet ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [Timestamp.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime%28%29)

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Timestamp object.

Example:

```
long timeInMilliSeconds = t.getTime();
// do magic trick here
```

Note: [Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is extend from [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Comment: +1, but... Welcome to the future, we use [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime%28%29) here.

Answer (score 4):

You can just call [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Timestamp.html#getTime%28%29) to get milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Is that what you were after, or did you want "milliseconds within the second" or something similar?

Note that using *just* milliseconds is slightly odd for a `Timestamp`, given that it's designed specifically to be precise to the nanosecond. So you should usually be using `getTime()` in conjunction with `getNanos()`.

Answer (score 2):

From the Java Docu ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime%28%29)):

> public long getTime()
>
> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Timestamp object.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will give the output you want.

```
public void timeInMills(Timestamp t){
    System.out.println("Time in Milli second "+t.getTime());

}
```